# Testing controller name that breaks naming convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2

I have called my controller

```
UtilityDREventsController
```

though it is defined in the file named

```
utility_dr_events_controller.rb.
```

The application is working fine the only thing I had to do was to pass

```
resources :utility_dr_events, :controller => 'UtilityDREvents'
```

when defining routes in routes.rb.
But I have issues when I want to write spec for it:

```
describe UtilityDREventsController do
  describe :index do
    it "should be redirect" do
      get :index
      response.should be_redirect
    end
  end
end
```

It is failing with such error:

```
1) UtilityDREventsController index should be redirect
   Failure/Error: get :index
   ActionController::RoutingError:
     No route matches {:controller=>"utility_dr_events"}
   # ./spec/controllers/utility_dr_events_controller_spec.rb:4:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've tried passing :controller option like that:

```
get :index, :controller => 'UtilityDREvents'
```

But without luck.
Anyone have some idea?

Comment: `utility_dr_events` should be `UtilityDrEvents`, but `utility_d_r_events` would be `UtilityDREvents`. An unconventional name like this can be trouble.

Comment: Yep. Best to rename the controller, but there might possibly be something to work with within Inflections.

Comment: Rails is all about convention over configuration. I'd stick as close to convention as possible to avoid pain.

Comment: Yes I know about the convention. I just wanted to be exact with specification I am implementing and one of the entities is named UtilityDREvent. I think that Inflections only handle pluralization of Strings not the loading of the missing constants.